# Linked pages can't load entry-variable

Tags: entries, entry, error, link

I'm a newbie with Craft CMS and just setup my templates. I got multiple .twig files for six pages. If I load my homepage "from scratch" my entries are shown as I want them to. But if I click on a link from another page back to my homepage, the entries are not loaded anymore and I get an error.

Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError
Variable "entry" does not exist.

How do I fix this? I don't know if you would need more information to help. Just let me know.
Thanks for the help in advance! And sorry for being a newb.

Answer (score 1):

The `Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError Variable "entry" does not exist.` typically happens when the variable has not been declared on the twig file getting pulled.

Its hard to suggest a solution without screenshots or code examples but I *think* if you check you have declared your entry variable in the `homepage.twig` file it should resolve.

Another reason why this error occurs is if the first instance of the variable is declared within an `if` or `for` statement and called again after said statement. The error happens during this time when the `if`/`for` is false and doesn't run, therefor the file never sees the variable created. If this is the case I suggest creating an empty `set entry = ""` before your `if`/`for` statement.

Below are some very high-level examples of what would cause this error and what would not.

---

**Example that would cause error:**

```
//head.twig
{% set entry = value %}

//homepage.twig
{% extends "head.twig" %}
{{ entry }}
```

---

**Example that would cause error:**

```
//homepage.twig
{% if x = y %}
   {% set entry = value %}
{% endif %}

{{ entry }}
```

---

**Example that would not cause error:**

```
//homepage.twig
{% set entry = '' %}

{% if x = y %}
   {% set entry = value %}
{% endif %}

{{ entry }}
```

If you fixed this already I am curious to know what you did. Hopefully my assumption is found helpful